# Adding a Legend to Pandas Scatterplot

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, data-visualization, legend, scatter-plot

I am using the Pandas version of Scatter, not Matplotlib. How would I add a legend to this graph based on the colors?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution: under the dat.plot.scatter(), add `legend=True` like this:

```
dat.plot.scatter(x='SqFt', y='Price', c=colorZip, figsize = (15, 8), s = 100, legend = True)
```